# Check whether a file has serialized objects remaining

Tags: java, serialization, objectinputstream

I have a single file containing multiple serialized objects and want to deserialize and store them in an array list. For that I need to know when the object input stream has run out of objects/ File input stream has reached EOF. Is there any way to do that?

```
public ArrayList<Object> retriveAllObjects(String file) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
    FileInputStream f = new FileInputStream(file);
    ObjectInputStream obj = new ObjectInputStream(f);
    ArrayList<Object> array=new ArrayList<>();
    while(obj!= null){ /////////////java.io.EOFException
        array.add(obj.readObject());
    }
    return array;
}
```

`obj` is my object input stream. `obj.available()`returns an empty arraylist.
I also put a try final block to handle the error. It works. But doesn't it a bad practice to let a n exception happen?

Comment: I suggest you write and read the list as a single object and the library will check this for you.

Comment: @PeterLawrey thank you it works. But is there any way to serialize objects one by one and deserialize them one by one?

Comment: Yes, however you should first write the number of elements or add a poison pill